# Object not callable error accessing array

Tags: python, arrays

```
def readscorefromcsv():
    position = listusers.index(username)

    print(position)

    global pointposition
    pointposition = listscore(int(position))
```

I keep getting the error `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

I am trying to find the value for a specific position in an array

- `listusers` is an array of usernames, `listscore` is the array of user scores.
- `position` is the position of the username in the array.

Comment: What you're calling an "array" is called a `list` in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List elements can be accessed by `[]` . `listscore()` means, calling the method named `listscore`

```
 pointposition = listscore[int(position)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`listscore` is a list, by doing `listscore()` you get the error `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`. Use `[]` instead to access an item. And `index()` returns an integer, so you don't need to call `int()`. Try this:

```
pointposition = listscore[position]
```